# How to know if a user authorize my application on Facebook to send a application request instead of wall post?

Tags: facebook, request

I have a Facebook Application that send some contents to users wall that authorized my app, but some users dont have my application authorized(obvious) and i want check if it before send post wall (becuase i get an error) and instead of send a post i want send a application request.

How can check if user already have my app and send an application request?

Comment: Programming language you are using is?

Answer (score 0):

you can check from signed_request if he/she has authorized your app when he/she start using your app.

otherwise unless user granted  offline_access request, you can't check if user already authorized, while he/she is not using app.

the best way for you to have your user logs, then you do action upon your login logs